# Terminology for all elements of an ordered set $\geq$ a specific element.

Tags: terminology, order-theory

This is sort of a silly question, but I don't know whether there is a standard term for the complement of the segment of a well ordered sequence (or more generally, the subset of elements greater than or equal to a chosen element).

I don't like using $O(x)^c$ to refer to the set of elements $\geq x$ since it forces me to use the set as the universe I'm working in, and the notation doesn't seem to be standard.

Comment: Terminologies used in Lattice Theory include $[x)$ and ${\uparrow} x$. Perhaps there are others. (And of course, $(x]$ and ${\downarrow} x$ for $\{y:y\leq x\}$.) The terminology you are suggesting (supposing you use $O(x) = \{y:y\leq x\}$) also has the disadvantage that being larger than $x$ is not the complement of being smaller than $x$, as it would suggest.

Comment: @amrsa I was under the impression that $O(x)=\{y\mid y<x\}$. But that being said, I do agree that the notation is clumsy, hence the question.

Comment: That may very well be the case. I seldom came across strict orderings, and never with $O(x)$. Unless you were referring to the complementation part; in that case, I was thinking about orderings which are not total, and so ${\uparrow}x \cup {\downarrow}x$ is not the entire ordered set, at least for some elements $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call it the [upset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_set) ${\uparrow} x$ of $x$, which is pretty standard order theory terminology.

Comment: Let me suggest you to use, in these cases, ```${\uparrow}x$``` instead of ```$\uparrow x$``` because the curly braces will remove the space that the operation symbol adds.

Comment: Bernd Schroder, *Ordered Sets* (2nd ed. 2016), pp.31, 218, agrees, except that the term is hyphenated, thus: **up-set**. He also uses the term **filter**.